# Is $CPT$ Symmetry already broken?

Tags: cpt-symmetry, cpt-violation

i came up this paper recently: https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-08549-9 it describes the "CPT violation with decoherence effects" by Neutrinos.

This means CPT Symmetry is broken? And when yes why nobody is talking about? Or did i misinterpeted something?
And when no, why is it published on a Springer journal when it's kinda wrong?